# Metodo every para array en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs

Este codigo tiene la funcion de devolver true si todos los alumnos del array son chicas y falso si hay algun chico. Para esto utilize el metodo every para arrays en Javascript.

El problema es que me di cuenta que si el array esta vacio devuelve true, lo que me parece ilogico ya que deberia devolver false. Intente crear una condicion que en caso de que el lenght del array sea igual a 0 me devuelva false pero igualmente a pesar de ell0 me devuelve true si el array es vacio.

Dejo aqui el codigo:

```
const students = []

let allGirls = students.every(student => student.gender === 'female');


function allGirlsClassroom() {    
  let allGirlsClassroom;                        
  allGirlsClassroom = (students.lenght === 0) ? false : allGirls
  console.log(allGirlsClassroom)
}

allGirlsClassroom();
```

Lo que necesito resolver es si es correcto que este metodo me devuelva true si el array esta vacio o en caso contrario como podria corregirlo para que tome en cuenta esta posibilidad y me devuelva false si el array esta vacio.

Dejo tambien el array con alumnos:

```
const students = [{
  age: 32,
  examScores: [],
  gender: 'male',
  name: 'edu'
},
{
  age: 29,
  examScores: [],
  gender: 'female',
  name: 'silvia'
}]
```

Agradeceria muchisimo una ayuda con esta duda!

Comment: creo wue tiene algo que ver con como definiste allGirlsClassroom, proba poniendolo asi:
``function allGirlsClassroom() {
  let allGirlsClassroom = students.lenght === 0 ? false : allGirls;
  console.log(allGirlsClassroom);
}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> every opera como el cuantificador "para todo" en matemáticas. En particular con el arreglo vacío retorna true. (es una verdad vacua que todos los elementos del conjunto vacío satisfacen una condición dada.)

Entonces si es correcto que regrese true en un arreglo vacío, podrías en tu misma variable **allGirls** revisar la longitud del arreglo

```js
let allGirls = students.length > 0 ? students.every(student => student.gender === 'female') : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Agregando el método **some** te devuelve falso si esta vacío

```js
  const students = [];

  let allGirls = students.some((student) => student.gender === "female");

  console.log(allGirls);
```